# Real time face detection with Camera on swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, face-detection, avcapturesession, avcapturedevice

How can I do face detection in realtime just as "Camera" does? like white round shape around and over the face. I use `AVCapturSession` . I found that the image I saved for facial detection. Below I have attached my current code. it only captures image when I press the button and save it into the photo gallery. some please help me to create real-time round shape over according to the person's face!

code

```
class CameraFaceRecongnitionVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imgOverlay: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnCapture: UIButton!

    let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

    // If we find a device we'll store it here for later use
    var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        btnCapture.CameraButton()
        roundButton.RoundButtonForFaceRecong()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh

        if let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices() as? [AVCaptureDevice] {
            // Loop through all the capture devices on this phone
            for device in devices {
                // Make sure this particular device supports video
                if (device.hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
            // Finally check the position and confirm we've got the front camera
                    if(device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front) {
                        captureDevice = device
                        if captureDevice != nil {
                            print("Capture device found")
                            beginSession()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func actionCameraCapture(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        print("Camera button pressed")
        saveToCamera()
    }

    func beginSession() {

        do {
            try captureSession.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice))
            stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]

            if captureSession.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
                captureSession.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
            }

        }
        catch {
            print("error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        guard let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession) else {
            print("no preview layer")
            return
        }

        self.view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
        captureSession.startRunning()

       // self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
        self.view.addSubview(imgOverlay)
        self.view.addSubview(btnCapture)
    }

    func saveToCamera() {

        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {

            stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (CMSampleBuffer, Error) in
                if let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(CMSampleBuffer) {

                    if let cameraImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {

                        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(cameraImage, nil, nil, nil)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Swift 3

I have found a solution using AVFoundation that will create square face tracking in real time on iOS. I have modified some code here.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class DetailsView: UIView {
    func setup() {
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.7).cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 5.0
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()

    var session: AVCaptureSession?
    var stillOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    var borderLayer: CAShapeLayer?

    let detailsView: DetailsView = {
        let detailsView = DetailsView()
        detailsView.setup()

        return detailsView
    }()

    lazy var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer? = {
        var previewLay = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.session!)
        previewLay?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

        return previewLay
    }()

    lazy var frontCamera: AVCaptureDevice? = {
        guard let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) as? [AVCaptureDevice] else { return nil }

        return devices.filter { .position == .front }.first
    }()

    let faceDetector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy : CIDetectorAccuracyLow])

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        previewLayer?.frame = view.frame
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        guard let previewLayer = previewLayer else { return }

        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        view.addSubview(detailsView)
        view.bringSubview(toFront: detailsView)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        sessionPrepare()
        session?.startRunning()
    }
    //function to store image
    func saveToCamera() {

        if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {

            stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: { (CMSampleBuffer, Error) in
                if let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(CMSampleBuffer) {

                    if let cameraImage = UIImage(data: imageData) {

                        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(cameraImage, nil, nil, nil)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController {

    func sessionPrepare() {
        session = AVCaptureSession()

        guard let session = session, let captureDevice = frontCamera else { return }

        session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto


        do {
            let deviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)
            session.beginConfiguration()
            stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey:AVVideoCodecJPEG]

            if session.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
                session.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
            }

            if session.canAddInput(deviceInput) {
                session.addInput(deviceInput)
            }

            let output = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            output.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String : NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange)]

            output.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

            if session.canAddOutput(output) {
                session.addOutput(output)
            }

            session.commitConfiguration()

            let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "output.queue")
            output.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)

        } catch {
            print("error with creating AVCaptureDeviceInput")
        }
    }
}

extension ViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {
        let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
        let attachments = CMCopyDictionaryOfAttachments(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, kCMAttachmentMode_ShouldPropagate)
        let ciImage = CIImage(cvImageBuffer: pixelBuffer!, options: attachments as! [String : Any]?)
        let options: [String : Any] = [CIDetectorImageOrientation: exifOrientation(orientation: UIDevice.current.orientation),
                                       CIDetectorSmile: true,
                                       CIDetectorEyeBlink: true]
        let allFeatures = faceDetector?.features(in: ciImage, options: options)

        let formatDescription = CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription(sampleBuffer)
        let cleanAperture = CMVideoFormatDescriptionGetCleanAperture(formatDescription!, false)

        guard let features = allFeatures else { return }

        for feature in features {
            if let faceFeature = feature as? CIFaceFeature {
                let faceRect = calculateFaceRect(facePosition: faceFeature.mouthPosition, faceBounds: faceFeature.bounds, clearAperture: cleanAperture)
                update(with: faceRect)
            }
        }

        if features.count == 0 {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.detailsView.alpha = 0.0
            }
        }

    }

    func exifOrientation(orientation: UIDeviceOrientation) -> Int {
        switch orientation {
        case .portraitUpsideDown:
            return 8
        case .landscapeLeft:
            return 3
        case .landscapeRight:
            return 1
        default:
            return 6
        }
    }

    func videoBox(frameSize: CGSize, apertureSize: CGSize) -> CGRect {
        let apertureRatio = apertureSize.height / apertureSize.width
        let viewRatio = frameSize.width / frameSize.height

        var size = CGSize.zero

        if (viewRatio > apertureRatio) {
            size.width = frameSize.width
            size.height = apertureSize.width * (frameSize.width / apertureSize.height)
        } else {
            size.width = apertureSize.height * (frameSize.height / apertureSize.width)
            size.height = frameSize.height
        }

        var videoBox = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)

        if (size.width < frameSize.width) {
            videoBox.origin.x = (frameSize.width - size.width) / 2.0
        } else {
            videoBox.origin.x = (size.width - frameSize.width) / 2.0
        }

        if (size.height < frameSize.height) {
            videoBox.origin.y = (frameSize.height - size.height) / 2.0
        } else {
            videoBox.origin.y = (size.height - frameSize.height) / 2.0
        }

        return videoBox
    }

    func calculateFaceRect(facePosition: CGPoint, faceBounds: CGRect, clearAperture: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let parentFrameSize = previewLayer!.frame.size
        let previewBox = videoBox(frameSize: parentFrameSize, apertureSize: clearAperture.size)

        var faceRect = faceBounds

        swap(&faceRect.size.width, &faceRect.size.height)
        swap(&faceRect.origin.x, &faceRect.origin.y)

        let widthScaleBy = previewBox.size.width / clearAperture.size.height
        let heightScaleBy = previewBox.size.height / clearAperture.size.width

        faceRect.size.width *= widthScaleBy
        faceRect.size.height *= heightScaleBy
        faceRect.origin.x *= widthScaleBy
        faceRect.origin.y *= heightScaleBy

        faceRect = faceRect.offsetBy(dx: 0.0, dy: previewBox.origin.y)
        let frame = CGRect(x: parentFrameSize.width - faceRect.origin.x - faceRect.size.width - previewBox.origin.x / 2.0, y: faceRect.origin.y, width: faceRect.width, height: faceRect.height)

        return frame
    }

}
extension ViewController {
    func update(with faceRect: CGRect) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
                self.detailsView.alpha = 1.0
                self.detailsView.frame = faceRect
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edited *******

> Swift 4

Apple's own Vision frameworks available to detect face in real time from Swift 4. [click the link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/tracking_the_user_s_face_in_real_time) for document and sample app.

Comment: swift 4 showing few things deprecated. Can you please update the code in swift 4?

Comment: updated swift 4 code (with Apple's sample)

Answer (score 0):

To anyone looking for a working and update example, Apple's website has the best I have found so far: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/tracking_the_user_s_face_in_real_time.

You have to change two lines: in `AppDelegate.swift` you need to change line `15` to

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
```

And in `ViewController.swift`you need to change line `462` to

```
let cameraIntrinsicData = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_CameraIntrinsicMatrix, nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Based on this [article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1163620-face-detection-tutorial-using-the-vision-framework-for-ios)

### Details

- Xcode 10.2.1 (10E1001), Swift 5

Features

This solution allow:

- to check camera access
- to select front or back camera
- if no access to the camera show alert with link to the app settings page
- to highlight face (face rectangle + eyebrows, lips..)

### Solution

> FaceDetectionService

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import Vision

class FaceDetectionService: NSObject {

    private weak var previewView: UIView?
    private weak var faceView: FaceView?
    private var cameraIsReadyToUse = false
    private let session = AVCaptureSession()
    private lazy var cameraPosition = AVCaptureDevice.Position.front
    private weak var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    private lazy var sequenceHandler = VNSequenceRequestHandler()
    private lazy var dataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "FaceDetectionService",
                                                     qos: .userInitiated, attributes: [],
                                                     autoreleaseFrequency: .workItem)
    private var preparingCompletionHandler: ((Bool) -> Void)?

    func prepare(previewView: UIView,
                 cameraPosition: AVCaptureDevice.Position,
                 completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        self.previewView = previewView
        self.preparingCompletionHandler = completion
        self.cameraPosition = cameraPosition
        checkCameraAccess { allowed in
            if allowed { self.setup() }
            completion?(allowed)
            self.preparingCompletionHandler = nil
        }
    }

    private func setup() {
        guard let bounds = previewView?.bounds else { return }
        let faceView = FaceView(frame: bounds)
        previewView?.addSubview(faceView)
        faceView.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.faceView = faceView
        configureCaptureSession()
    }
    func start() { if cameraIsReadyToUse { session.startRunning() } }
    func stop() { session.stopRunning() }
}

extension FaceDetectionService {

    private func askUserForCameraPermission(_ completion:  ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video) { (allowedAccess) -> Void in
            DispatchQueue.main.async { completion?(allowedAccess) }
        }
    }

    private func checkCameraAccess(completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        askUserForCameraPermission { [weak self] allowed in
            guard let self = self, let completion = completion else { return }
            self.cameraIsReadyToUse = allowed
            if allowed {
                completion(true)
            } else {
                self.showDisabledCameraAlert(completion: completion)
            }
        }
    }

    private func configureCaptureSession() {
        guard let previewView = previewView else { return }
        // Define the capture device we want to use

        guard let camera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: cameraPosition) else {
            let error = NSError(domain: "", code: 0, userInfo: [NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : "No front camera available"])
            show(error: error)
            return
        }

        // Connect the camera to the capture session input
        do {

            try camera.lockForConfiguration()
            defer { camera.unlockForConfiguration() }

            if camera.isFocusModeSupported(.continuousAutoFocus) {
                camera.focusMode = .continuousAutoFocus
            }

            if camera.isExposureModeSupported(.continuousAutoExposure) {
                camera.exposureMode = .continuousAutoExposure
            }

            let cameraInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: camera)
            session.addInput(cameraInput)

        } catch {
            show(error: error as NSError)
            return
        }

        // Create the video data output
        let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: dataOutputQueue)
        videoOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]

        // Add the video output to the capture session
        session.addOutput(videoOutput)

        let videoConnection = videoOutput.connection(with: .video)
        videoConnection?.videoOrientation = .portrait

        // Configure the preview layer
        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        previewLayer.frame = previewView.bounds
        previewView.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)
        self.previewLayer = previewLayer
    }
}

extension FaceDetectionService: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else { return }
        let detectFaceRequest = VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest(completionHandler: detectedFace)
        do {
            try sequenceHandler.perform(
                [detectFaceRequest],
                on: imageBuffer,
                orientation: .leftMirrored)
        } catch { show(error: error as NSError) }
    }
}

extension FaceDetectionService {
    private func detectedFace(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {
        guard   let previewLayer = previewLayer,
                let results = request.results as? [VNFaceObservation],
                let result = results.first
                else { faceView?.clearAndSetNeedsDisplay(); return }
        faceView?.read(result: result, previewLayer: previewLayer)
    }
}

// Navigation

extension FaceDetectionService {

    private func show(alert: UIAlertController) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            UIApplication.topViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    private func showDisabledCameraAlert(completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Enable Camera Access",
                                        message: "Please provide access to your camera",
                                        preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Go to Settings", style: .default, handler: { action in
            guard   let previewView = self.previewView,
                let settingsUrl = URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString),
                UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(settingsUrl) else { return }
            UIApplication.shared.open(settingsUrl) { [weak self] _ in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.prepare(previewView: previewView,
                             cameraPosition: self.cameraPosition,
                             completion: self.preparingCompletionHandler)
            }
        }))
        alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: { _ in completion?(false) }))
        show(alert: alertVC)
    }

    private func show(error: NSError) {
        let alertVC = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alertVC.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil ))
        show(alert: alertVC)
    }
}
```

> FaceView

```
import UIKit
import Vision
import AVFoundation

struct FaceElement {
    let points: [CGPoint]
    let needToClosePath: Bool

    func draw(in context: CGContext) {
        if points.isEmpty { return }
        context.addLines(between: points)
        if needToClosePath { context.closePath() }
        context.strokePath()
    }
}

class FaceView: UIView {
    private var faceElements = [FaceElement]()
    private var boundingBox = CGRect.zero

    func clearAndSetNeedsDisplay() {
        faceElements = []
        boundingBox = .zero
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in self?.setNeedsDisplay() }
    }

    private func drawElement(context: CGContext, points: [CGPoint], needToClosePath: Bool) {
        if !points.isEmpty {
            context.addLines(between: points)
            if needToClosePath { context.closePath() }
            context.strokePath()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
        context.saveGState()
        defer { context.restoreGState()}

        context.addRect(boundingBox)
        UIColor.red.setStroke()
        context.strokePath()

        UIColor.white.setStroke()
        faceElements.forEach { $0.draw(in: context) }
    }

    func read(result: VNFaceObservation, previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer) {
        defer { DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in self?.setNeedsDisplay() } }

        let rect = result.boundingBox
        let origin = previewLayer.layerPointConverted(fromCaptureDevicePoint: rect.origin)
        let size = previewLayer.layerPointConverted(fromCaptureDevicePoint: rect.size.cgPoint).cgSize
        boundingBox = CGRect(origin: origin, size: size)

        func addFaceElement(from landmark: VNFaceLandmarkRegion2D?, needToClosePath: Bool) {
            guard let normalizedPoints = landmark?.normalizedPoints else { return }
            let points = normalizedPoints.compactMap { point -> CGPoint in
                let absolute = point.absolutePoint(in: result.boundingBox)
                let converted = previewLayer.layerPointConverted(fromCaptureDevicePoint: absolute)
                return converted
            }
            faceElements.append(FaceElement(points: points, needToClosePath: needToClosePath))
        }

        guard let landmarks = result.landmarks else { return }
        faceElements = []
        addFaceElement(from: landmarks.leftEye, needToClosePath: true)
        addFaceElement(from: landmarks.rightEye, needToClosePath: true)
        addFaceElement(from: landmarks.leftEyebrow, needToClosePath: false)
        addFaceElement(from: landmarks.rightEyebrow, needToClosePath: false)
        addFaceElement(from: landmarks.nose, needToClosePath: false)
        addFaceElement(from: landmarks.outerLips, needToClosePath: true)
        addFaceElement(from: landmarks.innerLips, needToClosePath: true)
        addFaceElement(from: landmarks.faceContour, needToClosePath: false)
    }
}
```

> Helpers

```
import CoreGraphics

func + (left: CGPoint, right: CGPoint) -> CGPoint {
    return CGPoint(x: left.x + right.x, y: left.y + right.y)
}

extension CGSize {
    var cgPoint: CGPoint { return CGPoint(x: width, y: height) }
}

extension CGPoint {
    var cgSize: CGSize { return CGSize(width: x, height: y) }

    func absolutePoint(in rect: CGRect) -> CGPoint {
        return CGPoint(x: x * rect.size.width, y: y * rect.size.height) + rect.origin
    }
}

import UIKit

extension UIApplication {
    private class func topViewController(controller: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        if let navigationController = controller as? UINavigationController {
            return topViewController(controller: navigationController.visibleViewController)
        }
        if let tabController = controller as? UITabBarController {
            if let selected = tabController.selectedViewController {
                return topViewController(controller: selected)
            }
        }
        if let presented = controller?.presentedViewController {
            return topViewController(controller: presented)
        }
        return controller
    }

    class var topViewController: UIViewController? { return topViewController() }
}
```

### Usage

```
private lazy var faceDetectionService = FaceDetectionService()

//....

faceDetectionService.prepare(previewView: previewView, cameraPosition: .front) { [weak self] _ in
    self?.faceDetectionService.start()
}
```

### Full sample

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    private lazy var faceDetectionService = FaceDetectionService()
    private weak var previewView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let previewView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        view.addSubview(previewView)
        previewView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        previewView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        previewView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        previewView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        previewView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        previewView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.previewView = previewView

        faceDetectionService.prepare(previewView: previewView, cameraPosition: .front) { [weak self] _ in
            self?.faceDetectionService.start()
        }
    }

    // Ensure that the interface stays locked in Portrait.
    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask { return .portrait }

    // Ensure that the interface stays locked in Portrait.
    override var preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation: UIInterfaceOrientation { return .portrait }
}
```

### More info

- [How to make UIImage using AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56507067/4488252)
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/tracking_the_user_s_face_in_real_time